# How to migrate from Material Design 2 to Material Design 3

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, google-play-services, material-design-3

I have an application which is designed using Material Design 2. I have not submitted that to Playstore yet.
I am now trying to upgrade that application to Material Design 3. AFAIK, the themes etc present in Material Design 3 will not work on below Android 12 devices. So, I am not able to understand how to support Material Design 2(for below Android 12) and Material Design 3(for above Android 12) in my app.

I understand that this must be some basic question but I am not sure how to achieve this. Do I submit different APKs to Playstore with MD2 and MD3 or within code, do I somehow check the version and decide what to apply?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you don't need to submit different versions to Google Play. Take a look at migration [article](https://material.io/blog/migrating-material-3) from material blog.

Comment: I have already went through that doc. It talks about how to migrate from MD2 to MD3. For example, replace `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` with `Theme.Material3.*`. But AFAIK, `Theme.Material3.*` doesn't work on below Android 12 devices.

Comment: It works as expected. Simply, versions below Android 12 doesn't support ui features that came up with Android 12 and it's shouldn't

Comment: But that is not the expected behaviour because I don't want my App to break on below Android 12. If the app is below Android 12, use the appropriate UI component.

Comment: You are doing something wrong and I can't say exactly what without code.